# Laravel Recursividade?

Tags: php, laravel, model

Seguinte, na minha `model`:

```
public function indicacao()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'indicacao','name');
}

public function todasindicacoes()
{
    return $this->indicacao()->with('todasindicacoes');
}
```

e meu `controller` assim

```
public function rede()
{

    $Usuarios = User::where('name', 'admin')->with('todasindicacoes')->get();
    //dd($Usuarios);
    $cont = 1;
    foreach($Usuarios as $usuario){

     $x =  $usuario->todasindicacoes;
     echo $x;

}
```

no final da contas isso me retorna um resultado e que pesquisa e outro resultado e assim infimamente, gostaria de saber e se tem como quantas veze isso rodou, 
pois, no banco tenho assim

```
|login    | indicacao |
|---------|-----------|
|matheus  | null      |
|fulano   | matheus   |
|beltrano | matheus   |
|ciclano  | beltrano  |
```

---

- matheus é nivel 0
- fulano e beltrano é nivel 1
- e ciclano é nivel 2

Comment: Você quer saber quantas vezes a query foi executada para retornar esses dados?

Comment: n exatamente,
quero saber, em q nivel fulano está,
no caso do exemplo beltrano ta no 2

Comment: `->with('todasindicacoes')` isso não está correto para esse caso especifico, não é um `scope` que você precisa criar?

Comment: cara, sou novato ainda em laravel, mas nesse caso ta funcionando bem do jeito q eu quero, bom quase rsrsrs

Answer (score -1):

**Lógica para resolver segundo o exemplo**

Para o seu exemplo você terá que criar uma lógica onde, por exemplo se o `usuario` for o `ciclano`, no índice da tabela onde esta o `ciclano` conferir se `indicacao != null`

Se for diferente de `null` vc deverá armazenar o nome contido em `indicacao` em uma variável temporária, e em outra variável somar 1

Então deverá buscar na coluna `login` pelo nome armazenado na variável, na coluna `indicacao` no índice da linha onde o nome está contido caso não seja null então guarda o novo nome na variável e soma mais 1 na outra variável

Realiza este `loop` até que a verificação do `indicacao` seja igual a `null`

Então vc terá em `usuario` o nome do `login` e naquela variável em que somava 1 o nível deste

**Melhor forma de resolver**

Porém uma forma muito mais simples de resolver é adicionar a esta tabela uma coluna contendo o nível do usuário

Não sei exatamente qual a lógica da sua aplicação para esse nível, mas provavelmente o seu cadastro vem vinculado a indicação, então no momento do cadastro basta consultar o nível de quem indicou e somar 1 (caso não tenha indicação é nível 0)

```
|login    | indicacao | nivel |
|---------|-----------|-------|
|matheus  | null      | 0     |
|fulano   | matheus   | 1     |
|beltrano | matheus   | 1     |
|ciclano  | beltrano  | 2     |
```

Assim quando vc quiser saber o nível de algum usuário, basta buscar na tabela

Comment: cara legal isso q vc talando, mas não teria como
pois o o fulano teria nivel 1 tb, pois o mesmo teria acesso a esse relatorio
é como fosse uma piramide

Comment: @MatheusGonzales então explique melhor, pois ao que deu a entender ao cadastrar o `fulano` vc teria no `form` a indicação deste, no caso `matheus`, ao consultar o nível do `matheus` este é nível 0 e nesse caso o nível de `fulano` seria `0+1` o que atribuiria a fulano um nível `1` como vc descreveu na questão

Comment: vc colocou `fulano e beltrano é nivel 1` o que da exatamente o que descrevi

Comment: fui um pouco infeliz na descrição de fato, porem ao fulano entrar no sistema, o mesmo possui uma rede, onde o fulano é o topo, é estranho isso, mas é assim, é coisa de multinivel

Comment: @MatheusGonzales ta mas então qual o nível do `fulano`? seria `0`?